# Create Azure SQL DB with ONLY AD Administrator

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template

I'm in the process of converting my Azure SQL DB to use Active Directory authentication.

I've added this snippet to my ARM template which correctly sets up the Administrator as the AD Group. So far, so good!

```
{
  "type": "administrators",
  "name": "activeDirectory",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
    "login": "[parameters('sql_ad_admin_username')]",
    "sid": "[parameters('sql_ad_admin_objectid')]",
    "tenantId": "[parameters('azure_ad_directory_id')]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[parameters('sql_db_name')]"
  ]
},
```

Now that I've got it working, I want to get rid of the old SQL Server Auth Administrator details from the ARM Template (and I want to store the template in source control, so obviously no credentials should be in it).

So, I tried deleting these `administratorLogin` and `administratorLoginPassword` entries from the file (after all they're not needed any more, I have an AD Administrator instead):

```
  "properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "admin",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "XXXXXX",
    "version": "12.0"
  },
```

However, after deleting those, I get the following error running the template:

```
Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value.
```

Now I'm a bit confused. Why can't I get rid of these? I am now using AD Authentication which is more secure than SQL Authentication, yet it seems to be forcing me to have a less secure username/password administrator login set up? How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure SQL Database, you cannot get rid of the initial SQL Administrator login and password. This is always required, however in the same way that you have parameterized the "login", "sid", and "tenantid" for the AD Administrator you could do the same for the "administratorLogin" and "administratorLoginPassword" values in the template.

The admin structure is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication#administrator-structure)

Comment: Shame... I'd like to keep the Production Parameters file in source control too but I guess this means it's not possible

Comment: You could keep it in source control as a separate file. 

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-parameter-file?tabs=azure-powershell)

Comment: Right, but then wouldn't that mean that the sql admin password is exposed in source control?

Comment: The parameters file could contain everything except the password and then you provide that at deployment time along with the other parameters in the parameter file - i.e. you can mix and match between a parameter file and command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Ivan's suggestion seems to work now.
ARM template reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers?tabs=json

I've tested it with this basic template and the deployment succeeded.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01-preview",
            "name": "<insertResourceGroupName>",
            "location": "<insertLocation>",
            "properties": {
                "administrators": {
                    "login": "<insertLogin>",
                    "sid": "<insertSID>",
                    "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                    "principalType": "<Group/User/Application>",
                    "azureADOnlyAuthentication": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, when we create Azure SQL server with ARM template, we have no way to not provide administratorLogin and administratorLoginPassword. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2014-04-01/servers)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I eventually went for:

Parameterise the password in the template, then configure the parameters file to get it from the Key Vault:

```
"sql_admin_password": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/MY_RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MY_KEY_VAULT_NAME"
    },
    "secretName": "SQLDatabaseAdminPassword"
  }
}
```

This avoids needing to have the password anywhere in source control OR anywhere in the CI system which would have been necessary to pipe it in as an explicit parameter

Credit: https://www.anexinet.com/blog/deploying-sql-azure-using-credentials-keyvault/

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find solution to get rid of sql admin credentials.
There's a parameter called **azureADOnlyAuthentication** added to `"apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview"` of [Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2019-06-01-preview/servers/administrators), but all the time I tried to put any value there the db deployment failed with timeout.

I like the solution [suggested](https://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/automatically-generate-a-password-for-an-azure-sql-database-with-arm-template) by Vivien Chevallier - to generate login and password for Sql Admin. I slightly modified it based on comments, also used random generated password as a prefix. The idea is to omit sql admin credentials parameters when you use AD admin credentials, so sql admin credentials are generated, the password is not stored anywhere, so there's no way to retrieve it. The template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    "sqlServerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the SQL Server."
      }
    },
    "sqlServerAdministratorName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name for SQL Server administrator."
      },
      "defaultValue": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, '{24CF6AE7-F4CA-44D7-8FBD-B7F85C0BDDF6}')]"
    },
    "sqlServerAdministratorPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The password for SQL Server administrator."
      },
      "defaultValue": "[concat('C3@TnTAjqVnr', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, newGuid()), toUpper(uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, newGuid())))]"
    },
    "sqlServerAdministratorADName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the AD user/group for SQL Server administrator."
      }
    },
    "sqlServerAdministratorADSid": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SID of the AD user/group for SQL Server administrator."
      }
    },
    "transparentDataEncryption": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Enabled",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Disabled",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Enable or disable Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) for the database."
      }
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name for the database."
      }
    },
    "databaseCollation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Database collation"
      }
    },
    "databaseServiceObjectiveName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the configured service level objective of the database."
      }
    },
    "sqlTier": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard"
    },
    "sqlSkuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "S1"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('sqlServerName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlServerAdministratorName')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[string(parameters('sqlServerAdministratorPassword'))]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "SqlServer"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServerName'), '/', 'ActiveDirectory')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators",
          "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
          "properties": {
            "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
            "login": "[parameters('sqlServerAdministratorADName')]",
            "sid": "[parameters('sqlServerAdministratorADSid')]",
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('sqlServerName')]"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServerName'), '/', parameters('databaseName'))]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
          "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "Database"
          },
          "properties": {
            "collation": "[parameters('databaseCollation')]",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('databaseServiceObjectiveName')]"
          },
          "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('sqlSkuName')]",
            "tier": "[parameters('sqlTier')]"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('sqlServerName')]"
          ],
          "resources": [
            {
              "comments": "Transparent Data Encryption",
              "name": "current",
              "type": "transparentDataEncryption",
              "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
              "properties": {
                "status": "[parameters('transparentDataEncryption')]"
              },
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('databaseName')]"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "sqlServerFqdn": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('sqlServerName')),'2015-05-01-preview').fullyQualifiedDomainName]"
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('databaseName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Example of generated parameters:

```
sqlServerAdministratorName           ka7bwq3hord7a
sqlServerAdministratorPassword       C3@TnTAjqVnrqquzzkrgjp4tuLS645X4JUANDU
```